# jQuery set selected option from data on page load

Tags: jquery, json

I have a page that uses jQuery to load an option dropdown on page load. That part works fine. I then want to set the selected option in the dropdown baised on the querystring if there is one - and default it if there is not one. The querystring is being recovered fine but I can not get the setting of the selected option to work. In the code below when I stop at the "debugger" line and examine Select0 it is undefined (after haveing been loaded successfully) but if I allow the code to keep running the dropdown is populated with the data from the ajax call. I am guessing that this is why the selected item is not being set - just can't figure out how to resolve it.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "myPage.aspx/MyWebMethod",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: "{}",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (states) {
               var jsonCodes = JSON.parse(states.d);
               for (var i in jsonCodes) {
                   $("#Select0").append(new Option(jsonCodes[i].regionname, jsonCodes[i].region_id));
               }
               var first = getUrlVars()["region"];
               if (first) {
                   $.fn.GetInventory(1, 10, reg, 'rank', 'asc'); // If there is a querystring use it
                   $("#Select0 option[text='" + reg + "']").get(0).selected = true;
               }
               else {
                    debugger;
                   var myText = 'United States';
                   $("#Select0 option[text='" + myText + "']").get(0).selected = true;
                   $.fn.GetInventory(1, 10, 'United States', 'rank', 'asc'); // If no query string default to USA          
               }
           }
       });
```

Comment: You're missing hash signs `#` before `Select0` in all your calls to `$()` but the first one. Is that a typo or the cause of your problem?

Comment: you need to correct your jquery selector `$("#Select0")`. you have missed # at couple of places

Comment: typo - this error stops excecution (with the hash tag #Select0). Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'selected': object is null or undefined

Comment: Modified example code to include the hashtags that exist in the running code - sorry about the typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to match a `text` attribute that does not exist. You cannot write:

```
$("#Select0 option[text='" + myText + "']").get(0).selected = true;
```

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$("#Select0 option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == myText;
}).get(0).selected = true;
```

Or, taking more advantage of the library:

```
$("#Select0 option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == myText;
}).first().prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: This worked like a champ and thank you so much - been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code.

```
$("Select0 option[text='" + reg + "']").get(0).selected = true;
```

This is incorrect. Change to ->

```
$("#Select0 option[text='" + reg + "']").get(0).selected = true;
```

Also :

```
$("Select0 option[text='" + myText + "']").get(0).selected = true;
```

This is incorrect as well. Change to :

```
$("#Select0 option[text='" + myText + "']").get(0).selected = true;
```

Should work.

Comment: The omission of the hashtag was a typo when putting the code here - in the actual code it is there. The error I get is: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'selected': object is null or undefined

Comment: Have you tried to change the .selected paramter to .attr("selected", "selected"); ?

Comment: I did not but the suggestion by @Frédéric Hamidi worked very well. Thank you for the input though.